# Hide border and resize (change zoom) upon print

Tags: css, printing, zooming, border, media

Site in question: http://www.blues-n-brews.com/paypal_receipt.php?tx=17G30980M69737722

I have this:

`<div id="print_special" style="width: 1050px; zoom: 0.8; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; border: 5px solid black">`

Of which when the user prints/previews I want it to change the zoom to 100% and get rid of the border.

I am trying:

```
@media print
{
    #print_special {
        border-style: none;
        border: 0px solid black;
        zoom: 1;
    }
}
```

But it is not working as thought. If I do `display:none;` it gets rid of the div as expected, so I know the @media print is working fine. What is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inline CSS is overriding your print style sheet. The simplest thing for you to do is to change your @media print {} style like so:

```
@media print
{
    #print_special { border: none !important; zoom: 1 } 
}
```

The !important part tells the browser that you don't want this value overridden by styles defined further down the cascade. To go further, I would recommend pulling all of the style information out of the mark up and putting it all into a CSS file that has your media queries within it, so that you don't have to worry about cascading problems. But if you're not inclined to do that, use !important.